# elementary OS sometimes one external monitor goes black when login

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem. I am using elementary os on laptop ThinkPad T570. I've installed Nvidia drivers through installing cube into it. I am using 2 external display, one is connected via VGA cable into my dock station and another one is connected via mini display port in a monitor to display port in my dock station. First I thought it was drivers since I was using Nouveau, but yesterday I installed Nvidia as I mentioned and the result is same. However, when I lock screen, all displays are up and running and showing. When I unlock first thing which bothers me it took like 20sec of blinking black to turned off the display to show actual screen. And in 9/10 cases one of the screens stays black ( normally one in display mini port ), when I get lucky all 3 display shows up and works perfectly fine.

As I mentioned I search online for a solution but what I found was drivers, I managed to install cube from Nvidia. Which should work fine. Still a bit newby into Linux. So if you need any additional pieces of information, just say will provide it.

Greetings,
Marko.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. StackOverflow is a site for programming questions. Maybe try https://superuser.com/?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. My bad. Will do that. Ty